# Watson Speech to Text asynchronous http interface - curl / java cannot Register a callback

Tags: speech-to-text

i am trying to register a callback url with watson STT as below (curl script only) and getting 400 error. node.js process listening on port 3000 to handle request. am i missing something?. Thanks much in Advance.

curl -X POST -u "apikey:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx9xRhxjF2QOqssMkUhLkzl0" "https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/v1/register_callback?callback_url=http://localhost:3000/results&user_secret=my_secret_key"

{
   "code": 400,
   "code_description": "Bad Request",
   "error": "unsuccessful response from the server"
}

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is localhost addresses are only accessible from your personal machine.  You need a server exposed to the internet for Watson to be able to call back.

Comment: Thanks much @DHerls. i don't know how feasible this option going to be, when we are in a secured cloud environment. Anyhow i will try with an available lab server.